# Are there any 2D aperiodic tilings that are the projections from a 3D lattice?

Tags: tiling, crystallography

I need to give a short talk to some students to introduce a few ideas related to quasicrystals. It's not a proper lecture, more of an "ice-breaker" as I am not that well versed myself.

It is common to use a tilted cut through a 2D lattice to produce an aperiodic 1D tiling of a line to introduce the idea of [cut-and-project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling#Cut-and-project_method)

[image: from "Does the cut-and-project method produce the Fibonacci chain?" https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4473449/284619]

Source: [Does the cut-and-project method produce *the* Fibonacci chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4473449/284619) (related and unanswered in SciComp SE: [How to take the Fourier transform of a Fibonacci chain in a Python script?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/41986/17869))

but I'm interested in focusing on 2D quasicrystals, cf. Matter Modeling SE m[Proposing a 2D quasicrystal; what are the necessary and sufficient conditions? (If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, or...?)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6993/201)

I found this wonderful applet that runs in a browser that cuts-and-projects with controls for number of dimensions and the tilt of the cut, but I think it always uses an n-dimensional cubic lattice, and there are others.

- https://gglouser.github.io/cut-and-project-tiling/

So far I can make something that *looks like* it might be aperiodic in 2D starting from 4D, but not 3D.

I want an aperiodic 2D tiling from 3D because I can then draw/render it by tomorrow :-)

**Question:** Are there any 2D aperiodic tilings that are the projections from a 3D lattice?

[image: screenshot from]

Comment: related but currently unanswered despite a few bounties: [What is 12-fold Stampfli-inflation tiling and where/how can I recognize it in this analysis of dodecagonal 30° twisted bilayer graphene quasicrystal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4412856/284619) see also ["How chiral is my tile?" Explanation for beginners how to tell if a tile or tiling is or is not chiral (if its boolean) or how chiral it is.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4714040/284619)

Comment: I am pretty sure that cutting 3D with ***any*** plane having irrational slopes to all axes will give rise to an aperiodic 2D tiling.

Comment: Interesting dias [here](https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/sp-s15-w1/Aperiodic_tilings_]_Boris_Solomyak,_University_of_Washington.pdf)

Comment: @IvanNeretin all we need is one existence example that *known/proven*, since some tilings can look aperiodic. Oh, I am beginning to understand; perhaps it's the 5 dimensions and the tiling rules that lead to Penrose tiles not admitting any periodic tilings, while a given irrational cut in a 3D cube leading to some rhombuses might be aperiodic, but those tiles might also admit periodic tilings?

Comment: You may be confused by the difference between an aperiodic *tiling* and an aperiodic *set of tiles*, which are different.

Comment: @DanRust is not a set of tiles *which only admits aperiodic tilings* called an aperiodic set of tiles?

Comment: A non-periodic tiling is one that admits no non-trivial translation that fixes the tiling. A set of tiles which only admits **non-periodic** tilings is called an aperiodic set of tiles. An aperiodic tiling is one who *orbit-closure* (or *hull*) contains no periodic tilings - in other words, you can't find arbitrarily large patches of the tiling that come from some (fixed) periodic tiling. All repetitive non-periodic tilings are aperiodic.

Comment: @DanRust so the answer to my question *as asked* "Are there any 2D aperiodic tilings that are the projections from a 3D lattice?" is "ya, plenty!" and the answer to the question which I did not ask (but now wish I did) if we can get 2D aperiodic tiles from slicing some 3D lattice is... I guess I'll have to ask that separately, or maybe should I quickly revise this question?

Comment: I guess a new question is in order. @IvanNeretin, upgrade your comment to an answer so this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may apply the same cut-and-project technique to any 3D lattice and a plane. Obviously, if the plane has irrational slopes to the axes, the resulting pattern will not be periodic.

[image: cut-and-project]

The nature of the tiles is another story altogether. Here, for example, we only have 3 different tiles, and they may produce all kinds of patterns, some periodic and some not.